# Django: how to let a user update time part of an aware datetime?

Tags: python, django

In my code, I want a user to be able to edit the start/end **time** of an object which contains start/end **datetimes**.

That why I'm trying to create a form to edit the time part only:

## Forms

```
class UpdateServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ModelForm is used just to get the object instance inside the form
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = tuple()

    start_time = forms.TimeField()
    end_time = forms.TimeField()
```

## Views

```
class ServicesUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Service
    form_class = UpdateServiceForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        """ overrided to get start/end times from start/end datetimes """
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['start_time'].initial = form.instance.start.time()
        form.fields['end_time'].initial = form.instance.end.time()
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.start = datetime.combine(form.instance.start.date(), form.cleaned_data['start_time'])            
        form.instance.end = datetime.combine(form.instance.end.date(), form.cleaned_data['end_time'])
        form.instance.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

It does not work because:

- `form.instance.start` returns an aware datetime (expected)
- `form.instance.start.time()` returns a naïve time.

I found in Django doc:

> Django only supports naive time objects and will raise an exception if you attempt to save an aware time object, as a timezone for a time with no associated date does not make sense.

That makes sense...but how to display to the user the right time in the form initial data when he updates it?
Thanks.